# Org-agenda doesn't find any items with a property search

Tags: org-agenda

I'd like to use org-mode to work with JIRA tickets. There's a package for this, [org-jira](https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira). When I run it, I get a file like this: `FOO` is my Jira project, and org-jira creates a file `~/.org-jira/FOO.org`:

```
* FOO-Tickets
** TODO Review big document                                      :FOO_5:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :assignee: waisbrot
   :filename: FOO
   :reporter: waisbrot
   :type:     Story
   :priority: Major
   :status:   Ready
   :created:  2019-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700
   :updated:  2019-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700
   :ID:       FOO-5
   :CUSTOM_ID: FOO-5
   :END:
:LOGBOOK:
:END:
*** description: [[https://jira.example.com//browse/FOO-5][FOO-5]]
  We made a document and now we're gonna read it.
** TODO Publish coverage reports                 :FOO_102:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :assignee: waisbrot
   :filename: FOO
   :reporter: waisbrot
   :type:     Story
   :priority: Major
   :status:   Planning
   :created:  2019-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700
   :updated:  2019-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700
   :ID:       FOO-102
   :CUSTOM_ID: FOO-102
   :END:
:LOGBOOK:
:END:
*** description: [[https://jira.example.com//browse/FOO-102][FOO-102]]
  We generate test coverage so we should publish it
```

That looks reasonable. Now I want to get a list of tickets that are "Ready" (and other states). I do `C-c a m status=Ready` and I find no items. Things seem to be working because `C-c a t` shows me a list of all the tickets, as I'd expect.

(I want to use Agenda for this because I have multiple projects which turn into multiple org-files and I want to search across all of them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `C-c a m status="Ready"`.  The [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) has more details on selecting agenda items by property.

Comment: Thanks! I'd read the manual and kept missing that the property-value was in quotes -- that was my problem.